# vimscriptで外部コマンドの出力結果を変数に代入する方法を教えてください。

Tags: vim

vimscriptで外部コマンドの出力結果を変数に代入する方法を探しています。

例えば、vimscriptでlsコマンドを実行し、その結果を変数に代入したいと思い、
下記のコードを実行したのですが、

```
redir => message
execute ":!ls"
redir END

echo message
```

message変数には":!ls"というコマンドそのものが代入されており、
lsの出力は代入されていませんでした。
lsの出力をmessage変数に代入するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 5):

`system()` 関数が使えます。

```
let message = system('ls')
```